# Is there a Python module/recipe (not numpy) for 2d arrays for small games

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am writing some small games in Python with Pygame & Pyglet as hobby projects.

A class for 2D array would be very handy.  I use py2exe to send the games to relatives/friends and numpy is just too big and most of it's features are unnecessary for my requirements.

Could you suggest a Python module/recipe I could use for this.

-- Chirag

[Edit]:
List of lists would be usable as mentioned below by MatrixFrog and zvoase. But it is pretty primitive.  A class with methods to insert/delete rows and columns as well as to rotate/flip the array would make it very easy and reusable too. dicts are good for sparse arrays only.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, I would try to just use lists of lists:

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]  -- probably pretty memory-inefficient and maybe slow too. But worth a try.

Comment: Numpy is pretty fast as it calculates everything in C. It is ideal for a game. It is not big as you said. Mine has 6906K. How large is your hard drive?

Comment: My hard drive is not too small, but as I said I build exes to share the games with friends and relatives and the problem is the _dial-up_ connection which connects at 45.2 kbps max. It would take ~25 mins to mail just numpy. Yes I am from the dark-ages. And thank you for your sympathies :)

Comment: `dict` may be good for dense arrays as well because *I think* that Python `dict` is at least as fast as `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the class. Don't know if it is a good or redundant but... Posted it here http://bitbucket.org/pieceofpeace/container2d/

Answer (score 6):

How about using a defaultdict?

```
>>> import collections
>>> Matrix = lambda: collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> m = Matrix()
>>> m[3,2] = 6
>>> print m[3,4]   # deliberate typo :-)
0
>>> m[3,2] += 4
>>> print m[3,2]
10
>>> print m
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(3, 2): 10, (3, 4): 0})
```

As the underlying dict uses tuples as keys, this supports 1D, 2D, 3D, ... matrices.

Comment: +1 that would be faster than using nested dicts. flat is better than nested

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would just be to use nested lists:

```
>>> matrix = [[0] * num_cols] * num_rows
>>> matrix[i][j] = 'value' # row i, column j, value 'value'
>>> print repr(matrix[i][j])
'value'
```

Alternatively, if you’re going to be dealing with sparse matrices (i.e. matrices with a lot of empty or zero values), it might be more efficient to use nested dictionaries. In this case, you could implement setter and getter functions which will operate on a matrix, like so:

```
def get_element(mat, i, j, default=None):
    # This will also set the accessed row to a dictionary.
    row = mat.setdefault(i, {})
    return row.setdefault(j, default)

def set_element(mat, i, j, value):
    row = mat.setdefault(i, {})
    row[j] = value
```

And then you would use them like this:

```
>>> matrix = {}
>>> set_element(matrix, 2, 3, 'value') # row 2, column 3, value 'value'
>>> print matrix
{2: {3: 'value'}}
>>> print repr(get_element(matrix, 2, 3))
'value'
```

If you wanted, you could implement a `Matrix` class which implemented these methods, but that might be overkill:

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, initmat=None, default=0):
        if initmat is None: initmat = {}
        self._mat = initmat
        self._default = default
    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        i, j = pos
        return self._mat.setdefault(i, {}).setdefault(j, self._default)  
    def __setitem__(self, pos, value):
        i, j = pos
        self._mat.setdefault(i, {})[j] = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Matrix(%r, %r)' % (self._mat, self._default)

>>> m = Matrix()
>>> m[2,3] = 'value'
>>> print m[2,3]
'value'
>>> m
Matrix({2: {3: 'value'}}, 0)
```

Comment: Added the "Matrix" class example just for the kicks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [pyeuclid](http://code.google.com/p/pyeuclid/) matches your needs -- (dated but usable) formatted docs are [here](http://partiallydisassembled.net/euclid/), up-to-date docs in ReST format are in [this text file](http://code.google.com/p/pyeuclid/source/browse/trunk/euclid.txt) in the pyeuclid sources (to do your own formatting of ReST text, use [the docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html)).

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants general 2D arrays, not just the 3x3 and 4x4 provided by pyeuclid.  However, I'm upvoting this anyway because (1) it seems like this module was created specifically for Pygame and (2) it was created by the guy who would later go on to create pyglet!  Oh, and (3) maybe those small matrices are what OP wants after all.